# Gmail and Thunderbird; changed password now won't connect - auth error

Tags: thunderbird, gmail

I changed my Gmail password. Updated on Blackberry - works fine. Updated on another email platform (Mailspring for Ubuntu - free version) - works fine. Tried to update on Thunderbird - auth error and keeps asking for the password over and over again. I haven't changed anything else, set on auth2 as before. I have 2 factor auth on Gmail and have had this for some time with no issues. Imap enabled. I haven't a clue why Thunderbird won't connect to Gmail. I love Thunderbird. For the moment I'm using the free version of Mailspring instead which is good, but I'd love to have Thunder as an option. Using version 60.9.0 with 18.04.3. Any help would be great!

Comment: This reference from Mozilla may be helpful https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/997698

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that and created an app code for TB. Unfortunately it just says 'pass word incorrect' when I use it when it asks for email and password. I can't think of anything else to try, apart from changing permanently from TB which I don't want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it now works after an upgrade to version 68.2.1 (64-bit) appeared in software updates. So it must have been something within the connection, out of my control. But the new version of TB is working fine, link with Google very stable.